# Joining multiple tables and counts from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Assume we have these three tables,

```
Customer
--------
id

Order
-----
order_id
customer_id

Refund
------
refund_id
customer_id
```

Is it possible to write a single SQL query to display the following information

cusomter_id | order_count | refund_count

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried @DannyJiang?

Comment: It would be nice if you iclude some sample table data as text and your expected output with data.

Comment: @DannyJiang please check the below query.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here **LEFT JOIN** is used because customer don't have any order or refund. **DISTINCT** keyword is used for remove duplicacy because same order/refund comes multiple time because of JOINING. Otherwise use subquery where retrieves customer wise order and refund counted value.

```
-- MySQL(v5.6 or higher or all version) 
SELECT id customer_id
     , COUNT(DISTINCT o.order_id) order_id
     , COUNT(DISTINCT r.refund_id) refund_id
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN Ordert o
       ON c.id = o.customer_id
LEFT JOIN Refund r
       ON c.id = r.customer_id
GROUP BY id;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=14abaf3ebce50adda66212aef1a1651c

Here using subquery and removing DISTINCT keyword from inside COUNT(). COALESCE() is used for replacing NULL value to 0.

```
SELECT id customer_id
     , COALESCE(o.order_id, 0) order_id
     , COALESCE(r.refund_id, 0) refund_id
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_id
                , COUNT(order_id) order_id
           FROM Ordert
           GROUP BY customer_id) o
       ON c.id = o.customer_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_id
                , COUNT(refund_id) refund_id
           FROM Refund
           GROUP BY customer_id) r
       ON c.id = r.customer_id
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=fdcd92e942cf486c3c909298c69953b6

**N.B.:** This query is applicable for all RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest (and best performing) approach is correlated subqueries:

```
select c.id,
       (select count(*) from orders o where o.customer_id = c.id) as num_orders,
       (select count(*) from refunds r where r.customer_id = c.id) as num_refunds
from customers c;
```